# appending a list (i am not able to execute this code)

Tags: python, list, append

```
def greet(x,y):
    z=[]
    z=x.append(y)
    return "Hi your ful name is : %s \n your firstname: %s \n lastname: %s" %(z.title(),x,y)

f_name=[]
l_name=[]

f_name=list(input("enter your firstname : ")) 
l_name=list(input("entere your lastname: "))

print(greet(f_name,l_name))
```

Comment: Is your goal just to print first name and last name in a string?

Comment: i want to append the string in list

Comment: You want something like `z = f'{x} {y}'`; there's no need for any lists in this code. `f_name` and `l_name` should just be simple `str` values.

Answer (score -1):

This happens because when we use x.append(y), the operation is performed on x and hence nothing is returned when we append() as it happens when we use sort() with a list.Hence z is None type object

Comment: `z` is *not* a list after the second assignment to `z`.

Comment: How?? both x & y are lists as both inputs are converted to lists as & when taken from the user. Hence z is also a list i guess!!

Comment: `x.append(y)` does not return a list.

Comment: yupp!! just tested it. Thanks!!